# How to create custom json structure (ansible inventory)

Tags: json, go

I am obtaining data from the [cloudstack API listVirtualMachines](https://cloudstack.apache.org/api/apidocs-4.4/user/listVirtualMachines.html), and trying to create a web service that will provide a [dynamic ansible inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) for certain hosts.

In my first tries, currently I am fetching all the data by doing a connection request and then within a loop parse all the output:

```
vms, _ := cs.Request(&cs.ListVirtualMachines{})

// use for the metadata _meta['hostvars']['IP']['key'] = val
hostvars := make(map[string]map[string]string)

// used per each host ['name']['hosts'] = [list]
hosts := make(map[string]map[string][]string)

for _, vm := range vms(*cs.ListVirtualMachinesResponse).VirtualMachine {
  ip := vm.Nic[0].IPAddress.String()
  if ip == "" {
      continue
  }
  hostvars[ip] = map[string]string{
      vm.DisplayName:            vm.DisplayName,
      "ansible_ssh_common_args": "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null",
  }
  if hosts[vm.DisplayName] == nil {
      hosts[vm.DisplayName] = map[string][]string{}
  }
  hosts[vm.DisplayName]["hosts"] = append(hosts[vm.DisplayName]["hosts"], ip)
}
```

My desired output needs this JSON format:

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "172.16.0.3": {
                "ansible_ssh_common_args": "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null",
                "displayname": "server 1"
            },
            "172.16.0.4": {
                "ansible_ssh_common_args": "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null",
                "displayname": "server 2"
            },
            "172.16.0.5": {
                "ansible_ssh_common_args": "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null",
                "displayname": "server 3"
            }
        }
    },
    "group1": {
        "hosts": [
            "172.16.0.3",
            "172.16.0.4",
            "172.16.0.5"
        ]
    },
    "sandbox": {
        "children": [
            "server1",
            "server2",
            "server3"
        ]
    },
    "server1": {
        "hosts": [
            "172.16.0.3"
        ]
    },
    "server2": {
        "hosts": [
            "172.16.0.4"
        ]
    },
    "server3": {
        "hosts": [
            "172.16.0.5"
        ]
    }
}
```

My first try was to create a huge map:

```
inventory := map[string]map[string]map[string]string{}
```

But that was covering only the structure of the `_meta` key :

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "x.x.x.x": {
                "key": "value"
            },
            "x.x.x.y": {
                "key": "value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Later I came with a struct:

```
type Ansible struct {
        Metadata Hostvars `json:"_meta"`
        Hosts map[string]map[string][]string `json:",inline"` // want to remove the Hosts key
}

type Hostvars struct {
        Hosts map[string]map[string]string `json:"hostvars"`
}

inventory := &Ansible{
                Hostvars{hostvars},
                hosts,
}


if err := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(inventory); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the returned JSON is adding both keys `_meta` and `hosts`:

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "x.x.x.x": {
                "key": "value"
            },
            "x.x.x.y": {
                "key": "value"
            }
        }
    },
    "hosts": {    <--- want to remove this 
        "server1": {
            "hosts": [
                "172.16.0.3"
            ]
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to just have the key `_meta` and at the same level (inline) have each key for every hostname, something like:

```
{
    "_meta": {...},
    "server1": {
        "hosts": []
    },
    "group1": {
        "hosts": []
    },
    "sandbox": {
        "children": []
    }
}
```

I have a guess this probably could be solved with a `map[string]interface{}` maybe that could allow a dynamic JSON object with dynamic key names/structure, don't know exactly, therefore, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need `_meta` and a variable number of other properties at the same level use a `map[string]interface{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You best bet is probably to let Ansible implement [json.Marshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) to "flatten" the JSON document on-the-fly.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := &Ansible{
            Metadata: Hostvars{
                    Hosts: map[string]map[string]string{
                            "172.16.0.3": map[string]string{
                                    "displayname": "server 1",
                            },
                    },
            },
            Hosts: map[string]Group{
                    "group1":  Group{Hosts: []string{"172.16.0.3", "172.16.0.4", "172.16.0.5"}},
                    "sandbox": Group{Children: []string{"server1", "server2", "server3"}},
                    "server1": Group{Hosts: []string{"172.16.0.3"}},
            },
    }

    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(a, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println(string(b), err)
}

type Ansible struct {
    Metadata Hostvars
    Hosts    map[string]Group
}

type Hostvars struct {
    Hosts map[string]map[string]string `json:"hostvars"`
}

// I don't *think* Ansible supports anything else in host groups, so it makes
// sense to define it as a struct.
type Group struct {
    Hosts    []string `json:"hosts,omitempty"`
    Children []string `json:"children,omitempty"`
}

// MarshalJSON implements json.Marshaler
func (a *Ansible) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // Define a map that we will encode at the end of the function.
    doc := make(map[string]interface{})

    // Add all the groups.
    for k, v := range a.Hosts {
            doc[k] = v
    }

    // Add the _meta key.
    doc["_meta"] = a.Metadata

    return json.Marshal(doc)
}
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/OKQHAG3vqIG